# how to pass value dynamically in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get current class value `<input type="text" id="contact_name1" name="name1"/>` In js i want to call like this `$('#contact_name1').on('input', function() { }`.

my question is how to write after underscore current class.
`$(#contact_"")`? `name1` changes for all classes.

Comment: Generally it's the IDs that should be unique, not the classes

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks. no problem I will change to class instead of id.

Comment: Your text mentions "current class" but your jquery uses `#` which is for ID.

Comment: While the IDs should be unique, you can give them all the same class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the *starts with* `^=` operator inside the attribute selector:

```
$("[id^='contact_']").on("input", fn);
```

```js
$("[id^='contact_']").on("input", function() {

  var suffix = this.id.split("_")[1];
  console.log( "ID: %s SUFFIX: %s", this.id, suffix );

});
```

```html
<input id="contact_name" name="name" type="text">
<input id="contact_surname" name="surname" type="text">
<input id="contact_email" name="email" type="text">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can tell me `<form id="contact">` js `var form_data = $("#contact").serializeArray();` this form `id` also i want dynamic

Comment: @husna use `$(this).closest("form").serializeArray();` if you're targeting a submit button.

Comment: `$("[id^='contact_']")` like this for example if it is a class how I have to write.

Answer (score 1):

I may suggest using starts with selector. and you can get your class name like this:

```
 $('input[id^="contact_"]').on('input', function(e) { 

var className = $(e.currentTarget).prop("class")

}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

i made this exemple few days ago

```
<script>

$("input").click(function(){ 
    var res="#"+$(this).attr('id') 
    $(res).show() 
});
</script>
```

just create a variable who contains the entire text and after this you can lauch your function :)

Comment: Hmm.. very smart !